# VoIP (and other) traffic forwarding to port 80

Tags: networking, voip

in my college we have a filtered network that won't let through VoIP calls of any kind (as well as blocking bittorrent clients).
I'd like to channel all the programs connecting to the Internet through the 80 port, something I did on Android with an app called Drony (which asked for permission to create a dummy VPN, actually a trick to channel all of the apps through the 8080 port).  Is there any way for Ubuntu to achieve this?